# How to calculate the frequency of a signal without knowing the sampling frequency using Matlab

Tags: matlab, frequency

I have a signal and I am using Matlab command pwelch to calculate the frequency of the signal, but the frequency I obtained is changed as I change the sampling frequency.

For example, when using sampling frequency equal to 8000[samples/sec], the frequency appears to be 1 Khz, while using 16000 sampling frequency the frequency of the signal appear to be 2 Khz.

Which is the correct frequency? And is there other method to calculate the frequency of a signal without a prior knowledge of the sampling frequency?

Comment: Without sampling frequency all you have is a set of values. If they switch from one to another faster(i.e. different sampling frequency) they describe a faster sinusoid => higher frequency.

Comment: Nope - it's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have the information about the sampling frequency $F_s$ of your digital data, the best option is to talk about dimensionless relative frequencies $f$, or *reduced frequency*. The frequencies you observe on periodograms will be $f = F/F_s$, where $F$ would be the true frequency (hoping you have no aliasing). This amounts to saying that your sampling period is $1$ (dimensionless) and that the maximum observable frequency in your signal is $1/2$.

However, it is likely that the actual sampling frequency can be obtained from the data file, the  experiment or sensor, a recorded phenomenon with known frequency (like the 50 or 60 Hz power) or the person who gave you that signal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what is the duration of each signal? If you are using known freqs  you can try to distinguish between them without calculating the exact frequency

> [using Zero Crossing Rate method](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31663-zero-crossing-rate/content/ZCR.m)

It counts the number of zero crosses through value 0. As more crosses the frequency is higher.

Comment: And how exactly is that going to help?

Comment: Maybe he means he wants to distinguish between freqs on a defined time

Comment: I think that this method help only with signal of single frequency